# How to decide if Flyswatter2 can support a particular development board or not?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, debugging, jtag, openocd

I am new to JTAG debugging and have already got a Flyswatter 2 unit with me. This is my first experience with any JTAG debugger so I am not really sure what to look for to find if its compatible with my development board or not.

I want to debug baremetal code which is running on my Raspberry Pi 3B.

I read the [Flyswatter2 product page](https://www.tincantools.com/flyswatter2/) and it says that "[Flyswatter2] can be used to debug and program all ARM and MIPS processors supported by OpenOCD" . In that case Flyswatter2 can be used to debug Raspberry Pi 3B, because openocd supports it.
Then the same page also lists out supported cores by Flyswatter2, but ARM cortex A53 is not listed. Probably the page is outdated? I am confused if Flyswatter2 is compatible with ARM Cortex A53 or not?

Also I did not find even a single page on web that demonstrates how we can debug Raspberry Pi 3B with Flyswatter2. Is it compatible?

Comment: Incredibly, there are some things that are possible to do but are not yet documented on the internet. It sounds like you will need to dive into the technical details of this yourself, or ask whoever made your "Flyswatter".

Comment: the flyswatter is just a board with an ftdi chip so as it says whatever openocd can do it can do. getting openocd to work with the raspberry pi is where the challenge is the flyswatter is not a challenge.

Comment: @old_timer. Thanks. I came across this page https://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/raspberry/jtagsetup/ that claims a cfg expected to work with RPi3 but I haven't tested yet. Please let me know in case you have already have a working cfg.

Comment: I did have success when it was arm11 based, but they have switched cores two times since then.  there are folks on the raspberry pi baremetal forums that I believe have had some success.